# How to respond with a status code 500 to an ajax jsonp request

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I have an application that fires an ajax jsonp request to a C# HttpHandler.

```
function RequestData() {
var parameters = 'value1=' + value + '&value2=' + value2;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://localhost:44300/checkvalues?' + parameters,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
    success: function (msg) {
        alert('all good')
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        alert(jqXHR.status);
    }
});
```

And here is some of the server side code.

```
if (OK)
{
    response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    response.ContentType = "application/javascript";
    response.Write(callback + "({ data: 'allOK' });");
}
else
{
    //error
    response.StatusCode = 500;
    response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
    response.StatusDescription = "error";
    response.End();
}
```

When OK is true, there is no problem. The ajax success function is called as expected. But the minute that I set the response status code to e.g. 500 to trigger the error section of the ajax request, the server response is never received - nothing happens.

How can I modify my response code to enter the ajax error section?

I can trigger a parse-error by changing the response, but I want to do it with Http Status Codes.

Comment: Why don't use send statusCode in JSON instead.

Comment: Look at the request in the webinspector (F12). What is the response status code? I would expect your `error` function to trigger.

Comment: @jcubic - It seems to me, that I would have to handle the error in the "success" section. It seems more logical to handle it in the error section - if possible.

Comment: `jsonp` requests are script requests , not XMLHtttpRequests. Error handling capabilities are different. See docs : `This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests`

Comment: @Halcyon The request fired is [link](https://localhost:44300/checkvalues?callback=jQuery18006971448138356209_1456151615496&value1=value&value2=value2&_=1456151695981) - if I copy that URL into a browser, the server responds correctly with an Error 500. So why is it not detected by ajax?

Comment: @Mr.Blonde it should. Do you see the request in the webinspector?

Comment: Look at the answers provided in the duplicate I linked.  Error doesn't get called for cross domain jsonp requests [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) `Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests. This is an Ajax Event.`

Comment: @Halcyon: Yes, I see the request. And it is marked with a red X in the inspector.

Comment: Suggest you implement CORS instead of jsonp

Comment: @charlietfl That is correct. jQuery documentation states that "Error" is not called when using jsonp.

Comment: in your HttpHandler, should indicate that it is json... response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

Comment: jQuery is being silly, you can detect an error, I don't know why jQuery chooses not to. You can write your own JSONp request implementation (it's actually fairly simple). To detect an error add a listener to `onerror` of the `<script>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect a JSONp error. I'm not sure why jQuery chooses not to.

Here is a JSONp implementation that doesn't use jQuery. You might need to tinker with it a bit to make it work. For instance I'm not sure how jQuery communicates the `callback_name`.

```
function jsonp(success_callback, error_callback) {
    var script, callback_name;
    var parameters = 'value1=' + value + '&value2=' + value2;

    callback_name = "generate random name";

    function after() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].removeChild(script);
        }, 1);
    }

    script = document.createElement('script');
    window[callback_name] = function (response) {
        after();
        success_callback(response);
    };
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = "https://localhost:44300/checkvalues?" + parameters + "&callback=" + callback_name;
    script.async = true;
    script.addEventListener('error', function () {
        after();
        error_callback();
    });
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}

jsonp(function () {
    alert("success");
}, function () {
    alert("failure");
});
```

Comment: Marked as correct - it works. I will however use the jQuery plugin as suggested in one of the dublicate links added by @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ : https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp - although I didn't find the http status code in that solution.